# How to recover from a DeviceLostException in DirectX for Managed Code (VB.Net)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, directx

NOTE: (I know DX for managed code is deprecated and I plan on rewriting the code with SlimDX when I get some extra time.) I have been having a lot of trouble trying to handle a DeviceLostException. Unlike most DX applications I am not continually rendering frames I am only rendering when the content on the screen needs to be changed. This makes following the guides for handling DeviceLostExceptions a little tricky. I am writing a program that uses Nvidia's 3D Vision technology to display stereoscopic images. My display class is a border-less windows form class stretched to full screen. I have a base class called BaseStimulusDisplay that sets up the basic form and DirectX device and then I inherit from it to create a StereoStimulusDisplay object used for the display of stereo images. (I do this because I have some other types of displays for different aspects of the program.) The way the class works is I have two list of objects (stereoObjects and singleEyeObjects) which are basically just objects that contain some DX surfaces and some position info to determine where the surfaces should be drawn on the screen. When I want to display the objects on the screen I call a RenderScene method which loops through each object in the lists of objects and uses the StretchRectangle method to draw the object surfaces to the backbuffer and then call the preset(). To try and handle the DeviceLostException I put the device.Present() which is at the end of the Render Scene method in a try block that looks like this:

```
    Try
        Me._device.Present()
    Catch ex As DeviceLostException
        'Indicate that the device has been lost
        deviceIsLost = True
        'Send a message to the debug output that the device was lost
        Debug.WriteLine("Device was lost... Attempting to recover device")
        waitForDeviceRecovery()
        renderScene()
    End Try
```

Here is the waitForDeviceRecovry. I make sure that I Dispose of all the objects that use video memory before I call the device.Reset() and I reallocate the surfaces after the call.

```
Public Overridable Sub waitForDeviceRecovery()
    Do
        Try
            _device.TestCooperativeLevel()
        Catch ex As DeviceLostException

        Catch ex2 As DeviceNotResetException
            Try
                For Each Val As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
                    Val.Dispose()
                Next
                For Each Val As SingleEyeImage In singleEyeList
                    Val.Dispose()
                Next

                Me._offScreenSurface.Dispose()
                Me._backBuffer.Dispose()
                Me._blankScreenSurface.Dispose()
                Me._leftEyeSurface.Dispose()
                Me._rightEyeSurface.Dispose()
                Me._backBuffer.Dispose()

                _device.Reset(presentParams)
                deviceIsLost = False

                For Each Val As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
                    Val.loadSurfaces(Val.objName)
                Next
                For Each Val As SingleEyeImage In singleEyeList
                    Val.loadSurface(Val.objName)
                Next
                createSurfaces()

                'Send a message to debug out put that the device was recovered
                Debug.WriteLine("The device was successfully recoverd")
            Catch ex As DeviceLostException

            End Try
        End Try
    Loop Until deviceIsLost = False
End Sub
```

Now if I run the code and hit Alt-Tab to cycle through my open programs and go back to the DX app the code crashed at the following line in the renderScene method with a InvalidCallException;

```
  Me._device.ColorFill(Me._leftEyeSurface, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), color)
```

Also if I Alt-Tab into another program (Not just cycle all they way through the list of apps back to my app) And then try to bring back up the app. The program never comes back up it just gets stuck in the do loop of the waitForDeviceRecovery method. By this I mean the device.TestCooperativeLevel() call keeps throwing the DeviceLostException and never the DeviceNotResetException.  I am adding the complete code for both my display classes below.

Below is the code for the base stimulus display.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.DirectX
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.PresentParameters

Public MustInherit Class BaseStimulusDisplay

Public displaySettings As DisplaySettings
Public _size As Rectangle                                          'Size of screen
Public _device As Device                                           'DX device object to interface with graphics card
Protected _offScreenSurface As Surface                                'Surface on which to draw the SteroScreen images
Protected _blankScreenSurface As Surface                              'Surface of all background color
Protected _backBuffer As Surface                                      'The DX backbuffer
Protected _adapter As Integer = Direct3D.Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter
Protected presentParams As PresentParameters
Protected deviceIsLost As Boolean = False

Public Sub New(ByVal displaySettings As DisplaySettings)
    'Make windows happy
    Me.components = Nothing
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    Me.displaySettings = displaySettings
    Me._size = New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.displaySettings.xResolution, Me.displaySettings.yResolution)
    MyBase.SetStyle((ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.Opaque Or ControlStyles.ContainerControl), True)
    Me.InitializeDevice()   'Set the device parameters and create the device

    Invalidate()
End Sub

Public Overridable Sub InitializeDevice()
    presentParams = New PresentParameters
    presentParams.Windowed = False
    presentParams.BackBufferFormat = Format.X8R8G8B8
    presentParams.BackBufferWidth = Me._size.Width
    presentParams.BackBufferHeight = Me._size.Height
    presentParams.BackBufferCount = 1
    presentParams.SwapEffect = Direct3D.SwapEffect.Discard
    presentParams.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One
    Me._device = New Device(_adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, CType(Me, Control), CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, New PresentParameters() {presentParams})
End Sub

Public Overridable Sub createSurfaces()
    Me._offScreenSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height, Format.X8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
    Me._backBuffer = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height, Format.X8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
    Me._blankScreenSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height, Format.X8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
End Sub

Public Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose()
    Me._offScreenSurface.Dispose()
    Me._backBuffer.Dispose()
    Me._blankScreenSurface.Dispose()

    MyBase.Dispose()
End Sub

Public MustOverride Sub renderScene()

Public MustOverride Sub closeDisplay()

End Class
```

Below is the code for my StereoStimulsDisplay and the StereoObject and SingleEyeObject:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.DirectX
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.PresentParameters

Public Class StereoStimulusDisplay
Private Const colorFormat As Format = Format.A8B8G8R8           'The sufrace color format to use
Private Const poolType As Pool = Pool.Default                   'The sufrace memory pool type NOT SURE WHAT THIS IS FOR

Dim stereoObjectList As List(Of StereoObject)
Dim singleEyeList As List(Of SingleEyeImage)

Dim _leftEyeSurface As Surface
Dim _rightEyeSurface As Surface

Public Sub New(ByVal displaySettings As DisplaySettings)
    MyBase.New(displaySettings)
    InitializeComponent()

    stereoObjectList = New List(Of StereoObject)
    singleEyeList = New List(Of SingleEyeImage)

    createSurfaces()

    renderScene()   'Double render call is a hack to make sure the stereo display gets triggerd
    renderScene()
End Sub

Public Sub addStereoObject(ByRef sObject As StereoObject)
    stereoObjectList.Add(sObject)
End Sub

Public Sub addSingleEyeObject(ByRef sObject As SingleEyeImage)
    singleEyeList.Add(sObject)
End Sub

Public Function removeStereoObject(ByRef sObject As StereoObject)
    sObject.Dispose()
    Return stereoObjectList.Remove(sObject)
End Function

Public Function removeSingleEyeObject(ByRef sObject As SingleEyeImage)
    sObject.Dispose()
    Return singleEyeList.Remove(sObject)
End Function

Public Overrides Sub createSurfaces()
    MyBase.createSurfaces()
    Me._offScreenSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((Me._size.Width * 2), (Me._size.Height + 1), Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
    Me._leftEyeSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((Me._size.Width), (Me._size.Height), Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
    Me._rightEyeSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((Me._size.Width), (Me._size.Height), Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
    Me._blankScreenSurface = Me._device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((Me._size.Width * 2), (Me._size.Height + 1), Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default)
End Sub

Public Sub displayBlankScene(ByVal color As Color)
    'Erase the lase frame from surfaces
    Me._device.ColorFill(Me._leftEyeSurface, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), color)
    Me._device.ColorFill(Me._rightEyeSurface, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), color)

    Dim destRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height)

    'If Not useData Then
    Me._device.StretchRectangle(Me._leftEyeSurface, CType(Me._size, Rectangle), Me._offScreenSurface, CType(destRect, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    destRect.X = Me._size.Width
    Me._device.StretchRectangle(Me._rightEyeSurface, CType(Me._size, Rectangle), Me._offScreenSurface, CType(destRect, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    'End If
    Dim gStream As GraphicsStream = Me._offScreenSurface.LockRectangle(LockFlags.None)
    Dim data As Byte() = New Byte() {78, 86, 51, 68, 0, 15, 0, 0, 56, 4, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}
    gStream.Seek(CLng((((Me._size.Width * 2) * Me._size.Height) * 4)), SeekOrigin.Begin)
    gStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    gStream.Close()
    Me._offScreenSurface.UnlockRectangle()

    Me._device.BeginScene()

    Me._backBuffer = Me._device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono)
    Me._device.StretchRectangle(
        Me._offScreenSurface, CType(New Rectangle(0, 0, (Me._size.Width * 2), (Me._size.Height + 1)), Rectangle),
        Me._backBuffer, CType(New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    Me._backBuffer.ReleaseGraphics()
    Me._device.EndScene()

    Try
        Me._device.Present()
    Catch ex As DeviceLostException
        'Indicate that the device has been lost
        deviceIsLost = True

        'Send a message to the debug output that the device was lost
        Debug.WriteLine("Device was lost... Attempting to recover device")
        waitForDeviceRecovery()
        displayBlankScene(color)
    End Try

    MyBase.Invalidate()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub renderScene()
    'Erase the last frame from surfaces
    Me._device.ColorFill(Me._leftEyeSurface, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), Color.Black)
    Me._device.ColorFill(Me._rightEyeSurface, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), Color.Black)

    'Write all steroscopic objects to both eye surfaces
    For Each stereoObj As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
        Me._device.StretchRectangle(stereoObj.leftSurface, CType(stereoObj.leftSourRect, Rectangle), Me._leftEyeSurface, CType(stereoObj.leftDestRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
        Me._device.StretchRectangle(stereoObj.rightSurface, CType(stereoObj.rightSourRect, Rectangle), Me._rightEyeSurface, CType(stereoObj.rightDestRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    Next

    'Write all single eye objects to their proper surface 
    For Each SingleEyeObj In singleEyeList
        If SingleEyeObj.displayEye = SingleEyeImage.EYE.Left Then
            Me._device.StretchRectangle(SingleEyeObj.surface, CType(SingleEyeObj.sourRect, Rectangle), Me._leftEyeSurface, CType(SingleEyeObj.destRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
        ElseIf SingleEyeObj.displayEye = SingleEyeImage.EYE.Right Then
            Me._device.StretchRectangle(SingleEyeObj.surface, CType(SingleEyeObj.sourRect, Rectangle), Me._rightEyeSurface, CType(SingleEyeObj.destRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
        ElseIf SingleEyeObj.displayEye = SingleEyeImage.EYE.Both Then
            Me._device.StretchRectangle(SingleEyeObj.surface, CType(SingleEyeObj.sourRect, Rectangle), Me._leftEyeSurface, CType(SingleEyeObj.destRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
            Me._device.StretchRectangle(SingleEyeObj.surface, CType(SingleEyeObj.sourRect, Rectangle), Me._rightEyeSurface, CType(SingleEyeObj.destRec, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
        End If
    Next

    Dim destRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height)

    Me._device.StretchRectangle(Me._leftEyeSurface, CType(Me._size, Rectangle), Me._offScreenSurface, CType(destRect, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    destRect.X = Me._size.Width
    Me._device.StretchRectangle(Me._rightEyeSurface, CType(Me._size, Rectangle), Me._offScreenSurface, CType(destRect, Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)


    Dim gStream As GraphicsStream = Me._offScreenSurface.LockRectangle(LockFlags.None)
    Dim data As Byte() = New Byte() {78, 86, 51, 68, 0, 15, 0, 0, 56, 4, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}
    gStream.Seek(CLng((((Me._size.Width * 2) * Me._size.Height) * 4)), SeekOrigin.Begin)
    gStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    gStream.Close()
    Me._offScreenSurface.UnlockRectangle()

    Me._device.BeginScene()

    Me._backBuffer = Me._device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono)
    Me._device.StretchRectangle(
        Me._offScreenSurface, CType(New Rectangle(0, 0, (Me._size.Width * 2), (Me._size.Height + 1)), Rectangle),
        Me._backBuffer, CType(New Rectangle(0, 0, Me._size.Width, Me._size.Height), Rectangle), TextureFilter.None)
    Me._backBuffer.ReleaseGraphics()
    Me._device.EndScene()

    Try
        Me._device.Present()
    Catch ex As DeviceLostException
        'Indicate that the device has been lost
        deviceIsLost = True
        'Send a message to the debug output that the device was lost
        Debug.WriteLine("Device was lost... Attempting to recover device")
        waitForDeviceRecovery()
        renderScene()
    End Try
    MyBase.Invalidate()

End Sub

Public Overridable Sub waitForDeviceRecovery()
    Do
        Try
            _device.TestCooperativeLevel()
        Catch ex As DeviceLostException

        Catch ex2 As DeviceNotResetException
            Try
                For Each Val As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
                    Val.Dispose()
                Next
                For Each Val As SingleEyeImage In singleEyeList
                    Val.Dispose()
                Next

                Me._offScreenSurface.Dispose()
                Me._backBuffer.Dispose()
                Me._blankScreenSurface.Dispose()
                Me._leftEyeSurface.Dispose()
                Me._rightEyeSurface.Dispose()
                Me._backBuffer.Dispose()

                _device.Reset(presentParams)
                deviceIsLost = False

                For Each Val As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
                    Val.loadSurfaces(Val.objName)
                Next
                For Each Val As SingleEyeImage In singleEyeList
                    Val.loadSurface(Val.objName)
                Next
                createSurfaces()

                'Send a message to debug out put that the device was recovered
                Debug.WriteLine("The device was successfully recoverd")
            Catch ex As DeviceLostException

            End Try
        End Try
    Loop Until deviceIsLost = False
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub closeDisplay()
    For Each val As StereoObject In stereoObjectList
        val.Dispose()
    Next

    For Each val As SingleEyeImage In singleEyeList
        val.Dispose()
    Next

    MyBase.Dispose()
    Dispose()
    Close()
End Sub

Public Shared Function computeDispayableDisparity(ByVal requestedLevel As Double,
                                                  ByVal displaySettings As DisplaySettings,
                                                  ByVal numSubPixelShifts As Integer) As Double
    Dim arcPerSub As Double = displaySettings.arcSecsPerPixel / numSubPixelShifts
    Dim leftOver As Double = requestedLevel Mod arcPerSub
    If leftOver < arcPerSub / 2 Then
        Return requestedLevel - leftOver
    Else
        Return requestedLevel - leftOver + arcPerSub
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Public Class StereoObject
    Public pos As Point
    Public objName As String
    Public actualDisparty As Double
    Public numSubPixelLevels As Integer

```
Private subPixelSurfaces As Surface()
Private subPixelImages As Image()
Private parentDisplay As StereoStimulusDisplay

Public leftDestRec As Rectangle
Public rightDestRec As Rectangle
Public leftSourRect As Rectangle
Public rightSourRect As Rectangle

Public leftSurface As Surface
Public rightSurface As Surface

Public Sub New(ByVal objName As String, ByVal pos As Point, ByVal disparity As Double, ByVal numSubPixelLevels As Integer, ByRef parentDisplay As StereoStimulusDisplay)
    Me.objName = objName
    Me.pos = pos
    Me.numSubPixelLevels = numSubPixelLevels
    Me.parentDisplay = parentDisplay
    ReDim subPixelSurfaces(numSubPixelLevels - 1)
    ReDim subPixelImages(numSubPixelLevels - 1)

    ' Create and load the surfaces for all of the diffrent sub pixels images
    loadSurfaces(objName)
    Me.actualDisparty = updateDisparity(disparity)
End Sub

Public Function updateDisparity(ByVal newDisparty As Double) As Double
    Dim disparityDirection As Integer, pxlDisparity As Double, halfShift As Double, nPixelShift As Integer, fracDisparity As Double
    Dim nSubPixelShift As Integer, halfSubR As Double, halfSubL As Double, pxlR As Integer, pxlL As Integer, subR As Integer, subL As Integer
    Dim actualDisparity As Double

    'disparityDirection + backward;  - forward(crossed)
    If newDisparty > 0.0 Then
        disparityDirection = 1
    Else
        disparityDirection = -1
        newDisparty *= -1
    End If

    Dim test As Double = Me.parentDisplay.displaySettings.arcSecsPerPixel()
    pxlDisparity = newDisparty * Me.parentDisplay.displaySettings.pixelsPerArcSec()
    halfShift = pxlDisparity / 2.0
    nPixelShift = CType(Math.Truncate(halfShift), Integer)
    fracDisparity = halfShift - nPixelShift
    nSubPixelShift = CType(Math.Round(fracDisparity * 32), Integer)
    halfSubR = nSubPixelShift \ 2
    halfSubL = nSubPixelShift - halfSubR
    pxlR = nPixelShift
    subR = halfSubR
    pxlL = -nPixelShift
    If nSubPixelShift = 0 Then
        subL = 0
    Else
        subL = Me.numSubPixelLevels - halfSubL
        pxlL -= 1
    End If
    If pxlR = 0 And subR = 0 And pxlL = 0 And subL = 0 Then
        subR = 1
    End If
    actualDisparity = Me.parentDisplay.displaySettings.arcSecsPerPixel() * (Math.Abs(pxlL * Me.numSubPixelLevels + subL) + Math.Abs(pxlR * Me.numSubPixelLevels + subR)) / Me.numSubPixelLevels
    If actualDisparity = 0 Then
        subR = 1
        actualDisparity = Me.parentDisplay.displaySettings.arcSecsPerPixel() / Me.numSubPixelLevels
    End If

    If disparityDirection > 0 Then
        Me.leftDestRec = New Rectangle(pos.X + pxlL, pos.Y, subPixelImages(subL).Width, subPixelImages(subL).Height)
        Me.rightDestRec = New Rectangle(pos.X + pxlR, pos.Y, subPixelImages(subR).Width, subPixelImages(subR).Height)
        Me.leftSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(subL).Width, subPixelImages(subL).Height)
        Me.rightSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(subR).Width, subPixelImages(subR).Height)

        Me.leftSurface = subPixelSurfaces(subL)
        Me.rightSurface = subPixelSurfaces(subR)
    Else
        Me.leftDestRec = New Rectangle(pos.X + pxlR, pos.Y, subPixelImages(subR).Width, subPixelImages(subR).Height)
        Me.rightDestRec = New Rectangle(pos.X + pxlL, pos.Y, subPixelImages(subL).Width, subPixelImages(subL).Height)
        Me.rightSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(subL).Width, subPixelImages(subL).Height)
        Me.leftSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(subR).Width, subPixelImages(subR).Height)

        Me.leftSurface = subPixelSurfaces(subR)
        Me.rightSurface = subPixelSurfaces(subL)
    End If

    Return actualDisparity
End Function

Public Sub loadSurfaces(ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim name As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To numSubPixelLevels - 1
        name = Application.StartupPath & "\input\StereoObjectFiles\" & fileName & "\" & fileName & "_" & i.ToString() & ".bmp"
        subPixelImages(i) = Image.FromFile(name)
        subPixelSurfaces(i) = Surface.FromBitmap(parentDisplay._device, CType(DirectCast(subPixelImages(i), Bitmap), Bitmap), Pool.Default)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose()
    leftSurface.Dispose()
    rightSurface.Dispose()
    For Each surf As Surface In subPixelSurfaces
        surf.Dispose()
    Next

    For Each img As Image In subPixelImages
        img.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub setPos(ByVal pos As Point)
    Me.pos = pos
    Me.updateDisparity(Me.actualDisparty)
End Sub

Public Sub setToTrueZeroDepth()
    Me.leftDestRec = New Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, subPixelImages(0).Width, subPixelImages(0).Height)
    Me.rightDestRec = Me.leftDestRec
    Me.leftSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(0).Width, subPixelImages(0).Height)
    Me.leftSourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, subPixelImages(0).Width, subPixelImages(0).Height)
    Me.leftSurface = subPixelSurfaces(0)
    Me.rightSurface = subPixelSurfaces(0)
End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class SingleEyeImage
    Enum EYE As Integer
        Left = 0
        Right = 1
        Both = 3
    End Enum

```
Public pos As Point
Public objName As String
Private parentDisplay As StereoStimulusDisplay

Public displayEye As Integer
Public destRec As Rectangle
Public sourRect As Rectangle
Public surface As Surface

Public Sub New(ByVal objName As String, ByVal pos As Point, ByVal eye As EYE, ByRef parentDisplay As StereoStimulusDisplay)
    Me.objName = objName
    Me.pos = pos
    displayEye = eye
    Me.parentDisplay = parentDisplay
    loadSurface(objName)
End Sub

Public Sub loadSurface(ByVal fileName As String)
    'Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\input\SingleEyeObjectFiles\" & fileName & ".bmp"
    Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\input\SingleEyeObjectFiles\" & fileName
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
    surface = surface.FromBitmap(parentDisplay._device, CType(DirectCast(img, Bitmap), Bitmap), Pool.Default)
    sourRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height)
    destRec = New Rectangle(Me.pos.X, Me.pos.Y, img.Width, img.Height)
    img.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub setPos(ByVal pos As Point)
    Me.pos = pos
    Me.destRec.X = pos.X
    Me.destRec.Y = pos.Y
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose()
    surface.Dispose()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Did the _device.Reset() call return ok? Also, Managed DX has been deprecated for a while, is there a decent reason you're not using XNA?

Comment: Just seen your opening paragraph, disregard the second half of my comment.

Comment: Yes I think it is returning ok. At least it does not throw an exception.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used MDX, but if I remember correctly you should be handling the `Device`'s `OnDeviceLost`, `OnDeviceReset` and `OnDeviceDisposing` events. Then, inside the `OnDeviceLost` event handler, you should call the `OnLostDevice()` method for each object used in your scene, such as `Font` objects, for example.

Comment: Yes I have moved on to slimDX and have got it working. I think that I must have missed some resource that need disposeing. Maybe I will look back over my code and figure out what it was so I can have a conclusevie solution to this question.